# Why the Garbled Output when Replacing /* Comments?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace `/*` in selected text with `//`.

I used regex to do this. When I used any other strings it worked. But when I used:

```
String result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(seltext,"/*","//");
```

It shows:

```
/* int a,b;              // sample input

///*i//n//t//a//,//b//;  // sample output
```

Instead I want:

```
// int a,b;
```

Answer (score 3):

`*` has a special meaning in regular expressions - it means "match 0 or more of the preceding character/group".

It sounds like you don't want a regex at all - you just want

```
string result = seltext.Replace("/*", "//");
```

If you really want to use regular expressions, you need to escape the `*` (and various other characters, if you use them):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(seltext, @"/\*", "//");
```

Note the use of a verbatim string literal (indicated by the the `@` at the start of the string) to avoid having to escape the `\` as well for C# string literal reasons. You'd need to use `"/\\*"` which isn't as clear. Verbatim string literals are very handy for regular expressions.

I would suggest caution when trying to use simple text operations (including regular expressions) on source code though. For example, imagine applying the replacement to the first of the code snippets above...

Comment: Unless he also wants to replace `/***`, `/******` and so on... Not in the spec, though, so you're spot on about the literal replacement for the simple case. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Your Question is WHY.... wrong output?**

Let's start with the `WHY`, then we'll look at the fix.

**The core of the problem is that `/*` is able to match the Empty String**. Therefore, at Each Position, you insert `//`

**You Need to Escape the Quantifier `*`**

- In regex, `*` means "match what precedes zero or more times".
- Therefore, `/*` does not match `/*`, but rather, **the empty string (zero slashes)** or a series of slashes: `////`
- To match a literal `*`, escape it with a backslash: `\*`. Therefore your regex becomes `/\*`

**`/*` Matches at Every Single Position in the String**

- Because `/*` can match the empty string, it matches at every single position.
- Therefore, at each position, you insert `//`, hence your result

**In C# Code: Replace not only `/*` but also `/******`**

There is no need to use regex for a fixed literal `/*`, so to make it more interesting, we will not only replace `/*` but `/*****`. Do do so, we add a `+` quantifier after the `\*`. One line is enough:

```
string resultString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"/\*+", "//");
```

1. See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/2) to observe how we match at each position.
2. See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/3) to see how to do the replacement.

Comment: When i use "/\*" it is showing "unrecognized escape sequences error"

Comment: NOt forward slash, use a backward slash.

Comment: @abi, I added two demos. One shows the problem, and the other shows how to do it properly. Please have a look. :)

Comment: ya i used "/\*" it is showing "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: @abi With regex we are able to replace not only `/*` but `/***`, etc. I added one short line of C# to show you the replacement. :) It's the same regex with a `+` at the end to repeat the stars.

Comment: @abi Apart from how to fix it, the title of your question is about `WHY...` (`Why ... wrong output?`) I answered that in the question, does it make sense to you, or is it still unclear? :)